# Python return statement failing to return a list to be written into a pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, return

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this function is not returning anything. Any insight will be greatly appreciated!

Basically I create a list of string variables that I am preserving in a Pandas DF. I am using the DF to pull the variable to plug into the function via a .apply() method. But my return function yields `NONE` results in my DF.

```
def add_combinations_to_directory(comb_tuples, person_id):
    meta_list = []
    for comb in comb_tuples:
        concat_name = generate_normalized_name(comb)
        metaphone_tuple = doublemetaphone(concat_name)
        meta_list.append(metaphone_tuple[0])
        if metaphone_tuple[1] != '':
            meta_list.append(metaphone_tuple[1])
        if metaphone_tuple[0] in __lookup_dict[0]:
            __lookup_dict[0][metaphone_tuple[0]].append(person_id)

        else:
            __lookup_dict[0][metaphone_tuple[0]] = [person_id]
        if metaphone_tuple[1] in __lookup_dict[1]:
            __lookup_dict[1][metaphone_tuple[1]].append(person_id)
        else:
            __lookup_dict[1][metaphone_tuple[1]] = [person_id]
    print(meta_list)
    return meta_list
```

```
def add_person_to_lookup_directory(person_id, name_tuple):
    add_combinations_to_directory(name_tuple, person_id)
```

```
def create_meta_names(x, id):
    add_person_to_lookup_directory(id, x)
```

```
other['Meta_names'] = other.apply(lambda x: create_meta_names(x['Owners'], x['place_id']), axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Note: the print statement is printing the list as expected

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! it was a problem of nested functions. The return value from the `add_combinations_to_directory` was being returned to the `add_person_to_lookup_directory` function and not passing through to the dataframe.